# How to get all event logs of the contract in tron network using tronweb in node js without any limit?

Tags: tron, tronweb

How to get all events logs of the contract in tron network using tronweb in node js without any limit? or is there need of any middle ware storage like redis, etc?
Need to get all data at once before loading dapp home page. The dApp is made in react js. And Trongrid api have this limit of 200 records in single request.

Comment: Is there any overall limit in tronweb of nearly 10,000 requests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `fingerprint` (it works like continue token)

```
async getContractTransferEventsByUser(eventName, userId) {
        let result = [];
        let tronGrid = new TronGrid(this.tronWeb);
        try {
            let continueToken = '';
            while (true) {
                let res = await tronGrid.contract.getEvents(YOUR_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, {
                    only_confirmed: true,
                    event_name: eventName,
                    limit: 200,
                    fingerprint: continueToken,
                    order_by: "timestamp,asc",
                    min_timestamp: minTime, //remove if you don't need it
                    filters: { id: userId.toString() } //if you need to filter events by one or more values, for example, by user id (if this information is presented in event log), remove if you don't need it.
                });

                if (!res.success) {
                    console.warn("Can't get events for the contract");
                    break;
                }

                result = result.concat(res.data);

                if (typeof res.meta.fingerprint !== 'undefined') {
                    continueToken = res.meta.fingerprint;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        } finally {
            return result;
        }
    },
```

Comment: call above code within recursive function, thanks for help

Comment: This seems not working now. I always get, 'Exceeds the maximum limit, please change your query time range'' error

Comment: Exceeds the maximum limit, any solution to this issue?

Comment: One way is to break fingerprint request with some limit on event, to solve maximum limit issue, but still looking for better solution

Comment: get all events from contract with each transaction of the contract, it is better solution for limit issues

Comment: In the response, i got "from" and "to" address looking like ethereum address instead of trc20 address hex format. How do i go about converting this "0x" address to something more familliar please?